# Windows returns to login screen after login

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

After the creators update to 1803, I can not log in to my account anymore. When I log in, the LoginScreen opens again immediately

Comment: It seems to be a common problem. Do you have other users (even non-admin) on your systems that you can login with? If so, there is still hope.

Comment: Yes. I am logged in with an other Account. But I want to restore my main account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common problem when updating to 1803. It may only happen if you have more than one user account though.

Although you cannot login to your main account, you can still use its administrative capabilities if your other account hasn't admin access.

This allows you to create a new user with administrative privileges. You can then copy over your files from your non-working account which allows you to combat this problem without actually reinstalling Windows.

If your other user has Administrative privileges, you can just use the Settings menu to create a new user. If your other account does not have Administrative privileges, the following trick will allow you to create a new administrative user.

Start a command prompt as administrator. You can use the login credentials from your non-working account and it will work.

In the command prompt, execute the following 2 commands:

```
net user NewUsername * /add
net localgroup Administrator NewUsername /add
```

You can replace NewUsername with anything you want for as long as its a non-existing username on this particular system.

Now, reboot and login with the new user, and you can copy all files from your old profile into this one by going to C:\Users\OldUsername. If you copy the AppData folder, it should restore all settings for the programs you use, but it may break your account again, because we still don't know why exactly your profile becomes corrupt. Use with care.

Comment: Thank you! C: Is there a way to change the owner of my old user folder?

Comment: Yes, but that would not allow that profile to suddenly works. You really need to copy the files out.